# Iterating more efficiently

Tags: c++, collision

Is there a way to iterate trough my collision more efficiently ?
Because at 250 objects it would mean `250 * 250 == 62500` collision checks and it makes my game lags.

```
int sz = (int)objects.size();
for (int i = 0 ; i < sz ; ++i) {
    GameObject *iter = objects[i];

    if (!(iter)->Collidable()) { continue; }

    for (int i2 = i + 1 ; i2 < sz ; ++i2) {
        GameObject *iter2 = objects[i2];

        if (!(iter2)->Collidable()) { continue; }

        if ((iter)->CheckCollisions((iter2))) {
            (iter)->Collided((iter2)->GetID(), (iter2));
            (iter2)->Collided((iter)->GetID(), (iter));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into broad-phase collision detection to avoid an O(N^2) complexity.

Comment: The typical solution to this is to maintain a sorted list of objects in a geographic order, so that you don't have to check things that are far from the current object.

Answer (score 2):

Consider looking into [quadtrees](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves) (or for 3D, octrees).

These are data structures that keep things grouped by their relative positions, thus reducing the number of comparisons you need to do by focusing them only on things that are actually likely to be colliding.

Comment: Whats the advantage of quadtree over simple grid, I access the cell instantly with:int i = ( x - bounds.left ) / cell_width; int j = ( y - bounds.top ) / cell_height; return grid[i][j]; Does it require more complex search?

Comment: Quadtrees don't have a fixed grid size; they adapt to the number of objects in a location.

Answer (score 0):

I would first implement a space partition algorithm like an [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree), then I will implement different levels of collision detection. For example, sphere collisions are the cheapest, and then box collisions follow up, after that you can get more precise collision only if the objects first pass the sphere collision test.

Here is a link for collision test on two spheres [3d-Sphere collisions](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/simple-bounding-sphere-collision-detection-r1234).